# Create wordcloud based on dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, associations, word-cloud

i'm able to create a wordcloud on a PDF file. From that wordcloud, i picked out the  biggest word and found the associates. What i want to do now, is create another wordcloud based on the associates.

I placed the top10 associates in a dataframe and it looks like this: 
[image]

So my goal is to make a wordcloud where dvcsl is the center and node/omgeving/etc are around it. Anyone knows how to help me with this?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of your data.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this?

```
#Creating sample data
df<-data.frame(Name=c("node","omgeving","drie","elkaar","losse","dvcsl ","csl"),
                       Freq=c(0.59,0.52,0.4,0.37,0.36,2.0,0.35)) #'dvcsl' should have highest Frequency

#Order rows in decreasing order of frequency
df2<-df[with(df,order(-Freq)),]
row.names(df2)<-df2$Name

#Create word cloud with 'wordcloud2' package
wordcloud2(df2, shape = "circle")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Rar, thanks for your reply. In your example you're typing the names again, but i wanted to be done automatically.

Comment: I had to type the names because there was no reproducible example. However for you, the code starts from ordering the rows in decreasing order.

Comment: I figured something out, but I don't think it's really clean. I export the table from my first post to Mydata.csv and then import it to a dataframe. After importing it, i add the topword (in this case "dvcsl") twice to the dataframe and create a wordcloud based on that dataframe.
<br/>
    MyData <- read_csv("MyData.csv", col_names = FALSE,col_types = cols_only(X1 = col_character()), na = "null")
    newRow <- data.frame(X1 = topWord)
    MyData <- rbind(MyData, newRow)
    newRow <- data.frame(X1 = topWord)
    MyData <- rbind(MyData, newRow)